# Extract private key from keystore file in java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have a keystore file and i have some encrypted text. I have to decrypt it using my private key stored within keystore file. I am not able to figure out how to extract that private key within my java method.

```
public void decrypt(String encryptedText) {
    byte[] decryptedData = null;  
    try { 
      FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/Users/rajat/workspace/dev/abc.jks");    
      KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
      keystore.load(is, "abc".toCharArray());
      String alias = "xyz";
      Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "abc".toCharArray());

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");  
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);  
      decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText.getBytes());  
      System.out.println("Decrypted Data: " + new String(decryptedData));  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
     e.printStackTrace();  
    }   
  }
```

and when i run I get error as :

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:337)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
```

Comment: The problem here is the data length, not the key. But you shouldn't be passing ciphertext around as a String. String is not a container for binary data.

Comment: Actually I got this encrypted string from some response so I have to decrypt and check this value.

Comment: Can't really help you fix this without more context. How was the input string encrypted and then encoded?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you got the string from some response, if you have it as a String object then have done something very wrong.